# CORS issue in Azure API Management

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, azure, azure-api-management

I'm using Azure API management which internally access my python Flask web service. Azure API works good for GET operations. For POST, when I make jquery AJAX call, the request is converted into OPTIONS and the following error shows up

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://domain.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

I have added the following policy for the Azure API,

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <cors>
            <allowed-origins>
                <origin>*</origin>
            </allowed-origins>
            <allowed-methods>
                <method>*</method>
            </allowed-methods>
            <allowed-headers>
                <header>*</header>
            </allowed-headers>
        </cors>
        <base />
    </inbound>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
</policies>
```

But still I'm facing the same issue.

The same error showed up when I directly make AJAX POST request to my python flask service and I fixed it by adding the following code in the flask,

```
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
  response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Authorization')
  response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE')
  return response
```

What should I change in Azure API management to get the POST operation working??

Comment: I have recently noticed CORS failures in my Azure api's too, as of today. Is this a recent problem for you, too?

Comment: We noticed them too, started yesterday.

Comment: Yes. Very recent problem, wasted a whole day on this. Not expected from Microsoft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a CORS bug in the last release which is resolved now.

Answer (score 2):

Add below policy in API management -

```
<inbound>
    <cors>
        <allowed-origins>
            <origin>*</origin>
        </allowed-origins>
        <allowed-methods preflight-result-max-age="300">
            <method>*</method>
        </allowed-methods>
        <allowed-headers>
            <header>*</header>
        </allowed-headers>
        <expose-headers>
            <header>*</header>
        </expose-headers>
    </cors>
</inbound>
```

key Solution -
Delete -  base  tag under inbound tag and save .

Answer (score 1):

In my test,I set the wildcards(`*`) in `origin` tag, and I reproduced your issue, then I tried to specify the URL in allow-origins tag to development environment as `http://localhost:8801` instead of (`*`), and it posted through.

Here are my code snippets, for your information:

*Police:*

`<inbound>
    <cors allow-credentials="false">
        <allowed-origins>
           <origin>http://localhost:8801</origin>
        </allowed-origins>
        <allowed-methods>
           <method>*</method>
        </allowed-methods>
        <allowed-headers>
           <header>*</header>
        </allowed-headers>
    </cors>
    <base />
</inbound>`

*JS* code is the example shown on API management portal:

`$(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://garytest.azure-api.net/testpost/",
            beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
                // Request headers
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","{subscription key}");
            },
            type: "POST",
            // Request body
            data: {name:'gary',sex:'male'},
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            alert("success");
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert("error");
        });
    });`

*Flask service* is simple:

`@app.route('/post',methods=['POST'])
def post():
    name = request.form['name']
    sex = request.form['sex']
return "post name: "+name+", sex:"+sex`

Please try to specify origin, and test again.

Answer (score 0):

Temp ignore cors check with this config

```
<cors allow-credentials="false">
        <allowed-origins>
            <!-- Localhost useful for development 
            <origin>http://localhost:4200</origin>-->
            <origin>*</origin>
        </allowed-origins>
        <allowed-headers>
            <!-- Examples below show Azure Mobile Services headers -->
            <header>*</header>
        </allowed-headers>
        <expose-headers>
            <!-- Examples below show Azure Mobile Services headers -->
            <header>*</header>
        </expose-headers>
    </cors>
```